# Ruby: How to strip a string and get the removed whitespaces?

Tags: ruby, string, whitespace, strip

Given a string, I would like to `strip` it, but I want to have the pre and post removed whitespaces. For example:

```
my_strip("   hello world ")   # => ["   ", "hello world", " "]
my_strip("hello world\t ")    # => ["", "hello world", "\t "]
my_strip("hello world")       # => ["", "hello world", ""]
```

How would you implement `my_strip` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

```
def my_strip(str)
  str.match /\A(\s*)(.*?)(\s*)\z/m
  return $1, $2, $3
end
```

**Test Suite (RSpec)**

```
describe 'my_strip' do
  specify { my_strip("   hello world ").should      == ["   ", "hello world", " "]     }
  specify { my_strip("hello world\t ").should       == ["", "hello world", "\t "]      }
  specify { my_strip("hello world").should          == ["", "hello world", ""]         }
  specify { my_strip(" hello\n world\n \n").should  == [" ", "hello\n world", "\n \n"] }
  specify { my_strip(" ... ").should                == [" ", "...", " "]               }
  specify { my_strip(" ").should                    == [" ", "", ""]                   }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is a solution that I come up with:

```
def my_strip(s)
  s.match(/\A(\s*)(.*?)(\s*)\z/)[1..3]
end
```

But, I wonder if there are other (maybe more efficient) solutions.

Comment: lol, exactly the same as the one I came up with, except I added the multiline flag.

Answer (score 1):

```
def my_strip( s )
  a = s.split /\b/
  a.unshift( '' ) if a[0][/\S/]
  a.push( '' ) if a[-1][/\S/]
  [a[0], a[1..-2].join, a[-1]]
end
```

Comment: Splitting on word boundaries is going to cause problems, consider a string like " ... " which has no word boundaries.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the tip(anchors are your friends).

Answer (score 1):

I would use regexp:

```
def my_strip(s)
    s =~ /(\s*)(.*?)(\s*)\z/
    *a = $1, $2, $3
end
```

Comment: `my_strip("hello ")   # => ["", "hello ", ""]`

Comment: What's the difference between `*a = $1, $2, $3` and `a = $1, $2, $3` ?

Comment: @Misha Moroshko - fixed the issue above. I'm not sure for the asked difference. IMHO, the splat operator makes it clear an array is created.

Comment: Interestingly, you can even do `* = $1, $2, $3` (at least on 1.9.2)

Comment: @philippe: Now: `my_strip("hello world")` # => ["", "hello", " "]

Comment: Correct, fixed it again, which led to the same regex @Joshua Cheek came up with.

Answer (score 1):

```
def my_strip(str)
  sstr = str.strip
  [str.rstrip.sub(sstr, ''), sstr, str.lstrip.sub(sstr, '')]
end
```